# how to export to csv just the current page with front-end pagination using ag-grid?

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv, ag-grid

I am trying to make a grid where you can filter, sort, go to certain page ant export to csv only the page you are currently in. So far I got to the point where I can export filtered and sorted data. The last step would be to export only the page I am currently at.

I am using default ag-grid client side pagination with AngularJS.

A workaround would be perfect as well since I did not notice any documentation to achieve my goal.

Here are my gridOptions and exportCSV parameters.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,       
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    rowDeselection: true,
    enableColResize: true,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    suppressAnimationFrame:true,
    pagination:true,
    paginationPageSize: 100,
    onColumnResized: function(params) {
        console.log(params);
    }
};



$scope.exportCSV = function() {
    var timestamp = new Date();
    var params = {
        skipHeader: false,
        columnGroups: false,
        skipFooters: false,
        skipGroups: false,
        skipPinnedTop: false,
        skipPinnedBottom: false,
        allColumns: true,
        suppressQuotes: true,
        fileName: "Exported - " + timestamp,
        columnSeparator: ','
    };
    $scope.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);
   }
```

So by default it lets me to export only the filtered data and sorted data, but it skips the pagination part and exports all content of all the pages.

Comment: If you are not bound to ag-grid in any way, you can try out UI Grid. They have an example in their documentation to export data for the whole grid, as well as visible data, which is the current page in the grid. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data

Comment: How are you exporting just the filtered data? I imagine it would be very similar to exporting just one page, Could you include some code of what you are doing now?

Comment: @JarodMoser edited my post on your request